# Understanding a COUNTIFS() formula in Excel

Tags: excel

I am wondering if someone could explain the following formula in plain English:

```
=COUNTIFS('sheet4'!E:E,D2,'sheet4'!L:L," <="&TODAY())
```

I understand that COUNTIFS is just an incremental counter.  It's the rest of the formula that I'm not following. What are we counting / comparing, etc?

Comment: You are counting any row where column E equals the value of cell D2 and column L is less than or equal to today's date.

Comment: Count 1 for each row in the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) on Sheet4 if column E is equal to D2 on the worksheet that the formula is on and column L is earlier or equal to today. What part of the offcial [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) documentation wasn't clear?

Comment: @Jeeped `Countifs()` factors in the used range?

Comment: @Kyle - Yes that is true but to be succinct I wanted to make sure the OP knew that it didn't look in every row, just the [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772.aspx) of the full column ranges and the [.UsedRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) of hte worksheet.